# How to find the number of packages needing update from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, automation

I'm working on some system admin automation using fabric and I'd like to be able to monitor the number of packages that need upgrading on a given machine. This is the same information that I can see when I first log in to a machine, i.e. this part:

```
35 packages can be updated.
22 updates are security updates.
```

Is there a command that I can run (preferably without `sudo`) that gives just that information?

I've looked at the apt-python bindings, but they seem to have a high learning curve and they also appear to be changed around a lot -- I'd like something that will work at least as far back as lucid without needing to do different things on different Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To obtain that output, you can use the command

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
```

or, if you don't want to use `sudo`,

```
cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
```

#### Explanation

The `login` application shows the output found in the file `/etc/motd`, that is a symbolic link to `/var/run/motd`.

This last file is updated by the `mounted-varrun` service (see `/etc/init/mounted-varrun.conf`) invoking all scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`, and in particular

```
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
```

that in turn calls the script

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
```

this script executes various actions, and at last writes the output to the text file

```
/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the reboot part of the question, run this command

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required
```

it will give no output if reboot is not required.

Comment: I'm just checking on a machine running 11.04 and byobu shows 44 updates required. `cat`ing the file you suggest is blank, and the script you first point to doesn't exist on this machine -- is it in some package that needs to be installed? I have `/usr/lib/update-manager`, but no `update-notifier` directory.

Comment: Tested on 11.04 desktop. Those files belong to `update-notifier-common` that was installed automatically on a fresh installation (not upgrade from 10.10).

Comment: I've looked at some more machines. For those that have `/var/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` this looks like it returns the two numbers, i.e. 43;24 (43 updates, 24 are security ones), but even that doesn't appear on all my machines. I suppose that this file might have moved between packages in different versions.

Answer (score 24):

Why can't you just run this?

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

That's what /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available does to collect the information, at least in the version of Ubuntu I'm using (12.10).

Comment: Just checked on Lucid and it works there too

Comment: It writes its output to stderr. Who would do that?

Comment: Prefer this approach since it completely side steps the whole `update-motd` package and its thinking. Thanks for just giving the direct command.

Answer (score 4):

I also search for a scripred method for a update check inside minimal docker containers, when I found a comment in `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check`:

```
apt-get -s -o Debug::NoLocking=true upgrade | grep ^Inst
```

This allows a scripted update check, without the need to install the `update-notifier-common` package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `check_apt` plugin from `monitoring-plugins-basic` (*Nagios*), with the advantage of getting different return codes depending on whether updates are available:

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
APT WARNING: 18 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates). |available_upgrades=18;;;0 critical_updates=0;;;0
$ echo $?
1
```

Return codes have the following meanings:

- `0` --> no packages available for upgrade
- `1` --> non critical packages available for upgrade
- `2` --> critical updates available

References:

- https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_apt.html
- https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html