# apt-get count the number of updates available

Tags: apt

currently I use this to count the number of available updates

```
NUMOFUPDATES=$(aptitude search "~U" | wc -l)
```

Is there a way to do the same with apt(not aptitude) but not using the update-notifier?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/49958/20422

Comment: Your question has just answered mine, because for me aptitude is fine.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `apt-check` from `update-notifier-common`:

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

This is the same tool that updates the `motd` message.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the fastest method is shown in apticron:

https://salsa.debian.org/debian/apticron/blob/master/apticron#L121-154

This can be distilled to:

```bash
apt-get -q -y --ignore-hold --allow-change-held-packages --allow-unauthenticated -s dist-upgrade | /bin/grep  ^Inst | wc -l
```

Comment: Note the *-s* near the end, which means `simulate'

Comment: +1 for single integer output, and no extra packages or installs needed.
Thanks! this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-get -s` to simulate an upgrade process and extract only the number of upgraded packages by

```
LANG=C apt-get upgrade -s |grep -P '^\d+ upgraded'|cut -d" " -f1
```

This will result in just the number of packages

Answer (score -1):

I just run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After performing the update process, it gives the output for `upgrade` command as:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine1.5 wine1.5-i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 286 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

The 6th line mentions that there are 2 upgrades available and the 5th line lists the packages for which the upgrades are available. If I not in the mood to install the upgrades right at that moment I press <kbd>n</kbd> and move on.

Straight and simple.

Note: If there are kernal updates available as well, it would show them as `<x> not upgraded`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to retrieve this number in a form that can be used in a script, not just to see it.

Comment: Thanks, but all I need to get is just the number of updates available, in your example it is "2". Then the script shows notification "Available updates - 2"

Comment: @Eric Carvalho True.

Comment: @netcat: Oh... Don't know the answer then, I thought you just wanted to know how many number of updates are available casually (as I tend to do most often) :-)

Comment: @netcat: Would python script be okay for you? I might try to script that..

Comment: @Aditya: If it's possible to wrap it into bash script. Anyway I just wanted a script that checks for available upgrades and show the notify-send with the number of them and run it at login.